# Merging/Renaming/Synonym request for [softlayer] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Last year, SoftLayer was rebranded as IBM Cloud infrastructure as conveyed on the [SoftLayer's new name: IBM Cloud](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/info/softlayer-is-now-ibm-cloud) site.

As the Knowledge Manager for IBM Cloud Support, I am requesting that someone create the [ibm-cloud-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud-infrastructure) tag. We currently have the [softlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/softlayer) tag, which is used on most of the infrastructure-related questions for the IBM Cloud platform. We would like [ibm-cloud-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud-infrastructure) to be the master tag and [softlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/softlayer) to be a synonym tag. In the end, [ibm-cloud-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud-infrastructure) will show on all past and future questions about the infrastructure part of the platform. Here's a post in which the [softlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/softlayer) tag currently exists: [SoftLayer VLAN disassociate / detach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487841/softlayer-vlan-disassociate-detach)

Comment: I've created the  tag. A moderator needs to do the synonym

Comment: You guys and re-branding *grumble grumble* :)

Comment: @JonClements Hahaha...Well, its part of the larger rebranding last year.

Comment: Thank you for completing the change!